# Java threads: let EDT function wait for long running function off the EDT

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

Suppose I have a function refresh() which calls two other functions, one is a long running clearData() function which needs to be run off the EDT and the other is a quick function repaint() which is run in the EDT and which repaints the GUI components.

```
refresh()
{
   clearData(); //off the EDT function
   repaint(); //in the EDT function
}
```

what is a proper way to deal with the repaint when a longer operation like clearData() need to be run.
Is it letting the clearData thread run repaint() once it is finished a proper way? how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
refresh() {
    new Runnable(){
        clearData();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            repaint();
        });
    }.run();
}
```

Notice that repaint will be registered to be invoked after `clearData();` has returned, so, it's guaranteed that `repaint()` will execute after `clearData()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, run the `repaint()` after the `clearData()` is complete. You can use `SwingUtilties.invokeLater()` or similar to get the repaint() to run on the EDT.

**Possible implementation**

```
final Runnable CLEAR_THEN_REPAINT = new Runnable() {
    public void run() { 
        clearData(); 
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { repaint(); }
        });
    }
};

void refresh() {
    if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        new Thread(CLEAR_THEN_REPAINT).start();
    } else {
        CLEAR_THEN_REPAINT.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater will let repaint() run either before or after clearData, while I want repaint() to always be called after, however I dont want it to block waiting for clearData() otherwise the GUI would freeze. So invokeLater and invokeAndWait are not enough for this.

Comment: @dendini:  As I said "run the repaint() after the clearData() is complete." I only mentioned `invokeLater()` as a way to run `repaint()` on the EDT. The answer by Anas is exactly what I was suggesting, in code form (although his outer `Runnable` seems extraneous as it is not being run on another thread as presently written).